# Class Diagram for Course Registration

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I am making a class diagram for **Class/Course Registration** where students have to first register their course then select their class schedules (timetable)

I am unsure if I can have CourseRegistration and ClassRegistration table like that. The reason why I made it like that is, a student can register for a course but doesnt register to a class directly. so they can wait few days and then only register. So I have to make sure the course registration is saved in the database.

[image]

Thank you for all the help
PS: pls don't mind my attributes, they're just a draft.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's fine this way. You could alternatively use the association class notation like this:

[image]

Some side notes:

- labeling associations is not *that* helpful except you are on a business level analysis. Rather use role names on either end where appropriate.

---

**Edit** I somehow overlooked that you're designing tables. So my previous comment

- remove all the `id` attributes. Each object will have its unique id assigned by the runtime system. Use such an id only if it's of public meaning (e.g. a passport id or a student's registration number). And then use that specific name (e.g. `passportId`) rather than a `<class>id`.

goes just for basic class design. If you already have a (derived) table design you can just go with those ids.

Comment: Your statement that "each object will have its unique id assigned by the runtime system" is only true for some DBMSs, but not in general.

Comment: @GerdWagner As always: it depends. The OP is talking about a general class diagram and on that level you must not use any general IDs. So in your answer, where do you take the idea from the OP is talking about DB design??

Comment: Because the OP mentions tables, and because this is what you need when you build an app. Which "runtime system", except certain DBMSs such as MongoDB, assign IDs?

Comment: @GerdWagner Yes, you're right. He mentions tables. That wasn't obvious from neither the title nor the tags... I have to remove my remark about the ids.

Answer (score 0):

Your business logic for the registration process (register both for a course and a corresponding class) is too complicated. Normally, one would only register for a class, which would then imply taking the corresponding course.

Also, what does "ClassSchedule" stand for? Is an instance of a "ClassSchedule" a class meeting?

Since your model is supposed to define a design (of database tables and of, e.g., Java classes), each entity class should have an ID attribute defined, which is expressed in UML with the keyword "id" in curly braces appended to the attribute declaration. Having "ID" in the attribute names is not a formal declaration. Also, an ID attribute seems to be missing for `ClassSchedule`.